# Rpm spec confusion on rights and attributes

Tags: linux, unix, package-management, packages, rpm

What is the difference between `%attr` and `%defattr` and are the rights applied recursively to a file structure delivered by an rpm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%defattr` is a blanket for which its attributes will be applied across all files listed, while `%attr` is for specifying attributes *only* for a single file.

Answer (score 1):

%defattr, as the name implies, is the **default** attributes for all files in the package. What do mean by "applied recursively"? If you use a directory name, it will be used for all the files in the directory.